# Extract codes with regex (irregular codes)

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string

I´m extracting the codes from a string list using coming from the body of the email or subject. Looks something like:

```
text_list = ['RV: Final model review and algorithm COde 053 and also with CODE52','CODE22/coDe129','CODE178/coDe029']
```

So far what I tried is:

```
def containsDigit(word):
    if re.search("\d", word):
        return word

regex = re.compile('[CcOoDdEe]{4,}')
codes = []
codes_found = []

for text in text_list:
    codes_found.append(regex.findall(text))
    for code in codes_found:
        codes.append(containsDigit(code))
```

My issue is that, I´m not able to extract the digits next to the code or with a ' ' space in it.

My desired output would be:

```
codes = ['COde 053', 'CODE52','CODE22','coDe129','CODE178','coDe029']
```

Comment: Glad [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56593520/3832970) [worked for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56593360/extract-codes-with-regex-irregular-codes#comment99771167_56593520). Please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
text_list = ['RV: Final model review and algorithm COde 053 and also with CODE52','CODE22/coDe129','CODE178/coDe029']
rx = re.compile(r'\bcode\s*\d+', re.I)
res = []
for text in text_list:
    m = rx.findall(text)
    if len(m) > 0:
        res.extend(m)

print(res)
# => ['COde 053', 'CODE52', 'CODE22', 'coDe129', 'CODE178', 'coDe029']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/K4FGV7)

The `re.compile(r'\bcode\s*\d+', re.I)` regex matches `code` in a case insensitive way (due to `re.I`) as a whole word (due to `\b` word boundary) and then matches 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`) and then 1+ digits (`\d+`).

Comment: Nice. But the code works even without `\b` in the regex.

Comment: @Praveenkumar  I used it because I do not know the data but  I assume there can also be `passcode 12455` inside that OP would not like to match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew @Praveenkumar Thanks for the aid here! Just tried it, and works fine, just switched it to `res.append(m)` and else to leave it blank, so i can match per row (which are the emails).

Comment: @LucasMengual Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting the answer.